# Stepping through controls in a wrappanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bunch of controls located in  a wrappanel in a WPF app that are procedurally created. The first control is a label followed by a bunch of comboboxes and a checkbox. The user clicks a button and a new row of controls are added. This worked fine. Then I decided to make the label a bit more attractive by giving it a red circle as a background and the label was nested in a grid with the red circel behind the label that simply listed the row number. This worked fine. And I use to step through all the controls with this block:

```
 foreach (Control item in WrapPanelItems.Children)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                {
                    RowCounter++;
                }
            }
```

now suddenly this block of code fails with this error: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'.'

So I suspect the grid isnt a conventional item and the code fails. But how would I then iterate through the controls without the app crashing and still iterate through all the conventional controls ontop of it?

Here is the code for how I style and add the label.

```
        Grid MyGrid= new Grid();

        Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();

        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

        mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 107, 142, 35);

        myEllipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;

        myEllipse.Width = 20;
        myEllipse.Height = 20;

        MyGrid.Children.Add(myEllipse);

        Label LabelCounter = new Label();
        LabelCounter.Content = RowCount.ToString();

        MyGrid.Children.Add(LabelCounter);
        LabelCounter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        LabelCounter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

        WrapPanelItems.Children.Add(MyGrid);
```

And also a second question. Suppose I want to change the text on the label... how would I get to the label if its nested in a grid? Can you just change the content directly when the FOR loop picks up the grid? Or should you then say all children of grid when the grid is identified in the FOR loop?

tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grid` is not a `System.Windows.Controls.Control` so this line throws an exception:

```
foreach (Control item in WrapPanelItems.Children)
```

You can replace `Control` with `UIElement` to avoid this error.

---

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
public class Grid : System.Windows.Controls.Panel, System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild
```